# FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT + FREE_SELECTIONS_DIALOG - WITH Selection variant ? Any alternative or workaround?

Tags: dynamic, abap

Yes, as You can see, I use those two modules in exactly the right order, disable the tree on the left side and I am quite happy, that this works so easily.

But when we come to variants, it dumps. Ok, until now I do not react to that click, because I have not assigned any callbacks....

But I was already googling, and most of the stuff I found, stated, that I cannot use variants for this dynamic selection screens.

However, it does make sense in a way, to disable the functions.... but what, if 
I still want to have them ?

(Especially, because some jobs should be run at some, uncertain, dates )... using those variants...

Comment: What is the use of variants with `FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT`? What are you trying to achieve with it, that you can't achieve with static selection screens?

Comment: I want to populate the selection screen dynamically to allow a fully customizable generic masterdata mass change. Some of the parameters need to be populated by selvars in order to also process them in background, as standard jobs.

Comment: Wow-wow-wow, extremely bad scenario. Dynamic selscreens were not designed for this, they are redundant link in your chain. It's better to be done via background program or even better - via [low-level DB replication job](https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/demos/streams_demo1.html). Also you can look towards more professional products like [TDMS](http://sapbasisanswers.blogspot.com/2012/11/what-is-sap-tdms-test-data-migration.html) or [SAP MDM](https://help.sap.com/viewer/99218f2c48044ddc8f2ea30adc0e38a1/7.1.18/en-US/471c5928cd0412b8e10000000a1553f7.html).

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure, if You really get it... example in SAP standard is TA QA32, but designed differently.